# How do I read the last lines of a huge log file?

Tags: bash, tail, large-files

I have a log of 55GB in size.

I tried:

```
cat logfile.log | tail
```

But this approach takes a lot of time. Is there any way to read huge files faster or any other approach?

Comment: I found an approach in which it exports the output to a new file:

`echo "$(tail -1000 logfile.log)" > last_1k_lines_logfile.log`

This approach is okay, but I am curious on how to read that more efficiently

Comment: Your new approach would be better stated as `tail -1000 logfile.log > last_1k_lines_logfile.log` which puts it in line with @MarcusMuller's answer.

Comment: Not specific to this question, but if you think you need `cat` to send the contents of a single file to a command via a pipe, you are almost always wrong. The only times you should be using `cat` to feed a pipe is if you need to actually concatenate multiple files to operate on all of them (relatively rare these days) or the command you’re piping things to truly doesn’t support opening a file directly (also relatively rare these days).

Comment: You should also consider why you have a 55 GB logfile

Comment: `cat ... | tail` sounds like a cat-tail-problem. Same with `echo "$(tail ...)" > file`, just `tail ... > file` is better.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Not just "these days". Since the beginning it has been standard behavior for most tools to take filenames as arguments, defaulting to stdin only when there are no arguments. Exceptions have always been rare.

Comment: Obligatory: [Useless Use of `cat` award](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award)

Comment: You really should be looking at a better way of logging if you have a 55Gb log file.

Comment: many people have the same bad habit of `cat file | grep` instead of letting grep handle the file directly

Comment: @qwr Well, that *is* what he's trying to do :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`cat logifle.log | …` here is superfluous, and actually contributes to it being slow. `tail logfile.log` without the cat would make a lot more sense!

It's going to be much faster, because *when the input is not **seekable***, what `tail` needs to do is read all the standard input, line by line, keep the last 10 lines around in a buffer (in case they should be the *last* 10 lines); and having the input come from a pipe through your `cat` mechanism makes sure it's not seekable.

That is slow, and unless a line in your file can have gigabytes in size, pretty stupid: just skip the first 54.9 GB. The remaining 100 MB will certainly not be less than the last 10 lines! And getting the last 10 lines from 100 MB should be fast enough.

```bash
tail --bytes 100M logfile.log | tail
```

However, if you're using GNU Coreutil¹'s `tail` implementation, that already does this (i.e., it seeks to the end of the file minus 2.5 kB, and looks from there). By **not** abusing `cat` here but letting `tail` read the file itself (or just using redirection, works the same!) instead, you get a much faster result.

---

¹ GNU Coreutils, modern busybox are the two implementations of `tail` that I've checked; both do this. Stéphane points out below that even the original [1970s PWB Unix implementation](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/sys/source/s2/tail.c) does this – but it's still merely an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this helped me understand much easier the command `tail` command itself!

Comment: hmm, I always figured it'd be common for a `tail` implementation to seek close to end to find the last lines, but now I do wonder if it's only GNU that does that

Comment: @ilkkachu good question! A quick check of the busybox tail.c suggest they do it as well!

Comment: That's not limited to GNU `tail`. All `tail` implementations do that, including [the original implementation in PWB Unix from the 70s](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/sys/source/s2/tail.c). It's the `tail --bytes 100M` that is GNU-specific.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas excellent researching, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you're piping the two tail commands together.  It appears that (GNU) tail by itself will seek backwards until it find the last 10 lines, even if that's earlier than 2.5K from the EOF.  So, `tail logfile.log` is sufficient.

Comment: @jrw32982 I literally explain that in the second half of my answer!

Comment: using redirection only works the same because one has the [ability to detect if the redirected stdin was a file and get the name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1734243/995714). Technically it's purely a stream without fixed size so if the platform doesn't support that then the app always has to read and discard data in case of redirection

Comment: @phuclv, I'm not sure what exactly you refer to there. If you run `tail ... < file.txt`, then tail _can't_ get the filename, it only gets an open file descriptor (and anyway, there might not be an unambiguous filename, since there could be multiple hard links to the file), but it's also not just a stream, but a proper open file descriptor to the file, like any other you get when opening a file. And files can be seeked. It's not a question of the platform, but that of a file vs. a pipe.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your answer seems to focus on skipping to the last 100MB of the file using a technique which either has the same problem as the OP's solution (it will have to read the entire file) or it just seeks backwards from EOF, in which case why would you pick 100MB to seek backwards instead of just letting tail seek backwards 10 lines as it actually does?  Your answer is confuses the actual situation (tail is implemented properly) with a hypothetical counterfactual implementation, and even then it will not give guaranteed correct results when the last 10 lines start > 100MB from EOF.

Comment: @jrw32982 my answer explains (tries to, at least!), from first principles, why the implementation that `tail` has is good, and concludes with saying "so, yes, simply use the `tail filename` (as stated as first proposed command line); it seems that's not sufficiently clear, hm.

Comment: @jrw32982: That part of the answer is based on the fact that seeking based on a byte count is trivial, even the dumbest `tail` can be counted on to do that because it's also the most obvious and simple implementation for that part of `tail`'s functionality.  Marcus didn't want to assume that all `tail` implementations will seek to the end when given a line count the way GNU coreutils tail does, although from comments it seems that behaviour is widespread after all.  100 MiB is a generous over-estimate of the size of 10 lines in typical log files for example purposes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I think you've come up with a clever solution, and grown attached to it, and are loath to remove it now that you realize that it's unnecessary . . . and yeah, that sucks; but, well, it happens. You should still remove it, because it either fails or performs worse in all known implementations of `tail`, and it can only confuse or mislead readers who might think that this sort of complexity might be needed.

Comment: In terms of implementations, [BSD](https://github.com/sergev/4.4BSD-Lite2/blob/50587b00e922225c62f1706266587f435898126d/usr/src/usr.bin/tail/tail.c#L194) and [Toybox](https://github.com/landley/toybox/blob/master/toys/posix/tail.c#L76) also implement seeking, and whilst [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) doesn't require seeking, it does require tail to handle regular files differently to pipes and FIFOs (in terms of the -f option).

Comment: @MarcusMüller The reason it's not clear that you're actually recommending the simple `tail filename` is that the only "line of code" in your answer (as opposed to a "code fragment") is the `tail | tail` one.  So, from an initial reading, and even from further readings, the focus is on that one line of code and the actual answer you're recommending is buried in the rest of the answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems like Marcus' answer would unnecessarily confuse someone who was reading the accepted answer looking for the actual solution.  Also, as Stéphane pointed out, --bytes is not even POSIX.  So, the whole answer seems to be backwards, focusing on the incorrect approach, instead of the right one.  Personally, I have never even considered a `tail | tail` approach.  I just read the (GNU) man page, tried a few test cases and was done.  I probably would have gone with a `tac | head | tac` approach if the simple solution didn't just work.

Comment: @jrw32982: Ok, that's fair, the `tail big.log` correct answer could use more emphasis, like **bold** or a `---` section divider below a "TL:DR: do this" section, to draw the eyes of people skimming for a command to copy/paste, if they're expecting the actual recipe to be non-trivial and miss the fact that it's covered in the first paragraph.

Comment: @ilkkachu I was referring to Marcus' "or just using redirection, works the same" because on many OSes `tail ... < file.txt` **can** detect file name if it's smart enough, and actually many app implementations do that to avoid the streaming solution's downsides. But it's not a reliable way of course. Anyway it works on Windows, Linux, macOS & BSDs

Comment: @phuclv, there's no simple way to get the filename from the open fd, at best you could possibly walk the filesystem to find the correct inode, but that takes ages (even then, you'd just get _a_ filename, not necessarily the one used in the redirection). I would be _very_ surprised to see any tool in common use do that. `tail` doesn't need the filename for anything, it can just seek the open fd it has, if it's open to a file and not a pipe.

Comment: yeah, the thing that becomes the standard input of `tail` and behaves like a file has no reason to even have a filename :) For example, you could use `memfd_create` to create an *anonymous, RAM-backed* open file, get its descriptor, use `dup2` to replace `stdin` with that, and then use `execve` to run `tail`. (that "swap file descriptors and replace myself with the target process" is the trick how shells do redirection)

Comment: @ilkkachu it's possible, did you check the link? Once it has the name it'll just need to seek and ignore the input stream. Even in case of complex mounted files then it'll be much faster than slurping tens of GBs of data in the input stream and discard

Comment: @phuclv, yes, the linked Q&A says _"you can retrieve a filepath associated with stdin by using fstat to get an inode number for it then walking the file hierarchy similarly to find / -inum to get a path that matches it."_ So yes, in principle one can try to do it, but doing it that way is rather painful. And, again, there's no need for the filename. Just seek the fd the program already has.

Answer (score 17):

You should use directly `tail logfile` to get the last ten lines of the file without reading all the file as `cat logfile | tail` is doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -nX path to your log file
```

For X use the number of lines you wish to read.

Example

```
tail -n30 /var/log/syslog
```

Shows the last 30 lines of my /var/log/syslog

Comment: I think OP already knows what `tail` does.

Comment: `cat | tail` would suggest otherwise.

Comment: This answer is correct but doesn't explain that giving `tail` the path to the file (instead of using it as a filter reading from stdin) lets it seek instead of reading through the file from the start. The other answers do explain that, especially Marcus's.

Answer (score -7):

You can use `tac`, which is `cat` backwards. But don't, because it's hard to limit it to 10 lines. Use `tail` instead because that's what it's for.

Comment: Well, `tac FILE | head -n10 | tac` would give the right result, but it's needlessly complicated and slow when `tail FILE` would do the job.  But your answer doesn't explain why `tail FILE` works as OP wanted and `tail < FILE` doesn't.